# Jquery is not finding an id inside DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a
**HTML**

```
<h3 id="tourName_ROCK.ROCK"></h3>
<h3 id="tourName_MOBT.MOBT"></h3>
```

and **JSON**

```
dataTourBase :{
"list":[{
      "code" : "ROCK.ROCK",
      "name" : "Laugher Bins"
},
{
      "code" : "MOBT.MOBT",
      "name" : "Laugher Bins"
}]
```

In my Jquery code , I want to attach matching code with its name. But the problem is my DOM is unable to find the id because of "." (DOT) oprator

I am doing like this:

```
jQuery.each(dataTourBase.list, function(i, excursion) {
    $("#" + "tourName_" + excursion.code).html(excursion.name);
}
```

Please advice , how i can find my id in DOM.
Thanks in advance

Comment: the `.` is being interpreted as introducing a class name.  easiest solution is to not use `.` in ids  :)

Comment: It's because jQuery uses css selectors to find DOM elements. By having the period in your id you are telling jQuery to find an element with an id and also a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options, the first is the best – in my own humble opinion – remove the `.` characters from the `id`s of the elements; replacing them with allowed characters, such as `-` or `_`.

Otherwise, you'll have to escape the `.` characters in the strings using String.prototype.replace()`:

```
jQuery.each(dataTourBase.list, function(i, excursion) {
    $("#" + "tourName_" + excursion.code.replace(/\./g,'\\.').html(excursion.name);
}
```

The additional code:

```
replace(/\./g, '\\.')
```

Matches all literal `.` characters by first escaping it with the back-slash (since the period is a special character in regular expressions), and replaces that period with a sequence of two backslashes followed by a period; the first backslash escapes the second backslash which &ndash when used in the jQuery selector &ndash escapes the period, so that it's considered a 'literal' period, rather than identifying the following string as a class-name.

But, honestly, it's easier to avoid problems than code your way around them.

References:

- [Guide to JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 4):

CSS selectors. You're doing:

```
$('#tourName_ROCK.ROCK');
```

which Javascript is interpreting as "element with ID `tourName_ROCK` and CSS selector `ROCK`, e.g.

```
<div id="tourname_ROCK" class="ROCK">
```

would match.

In other words, don't use `.` in `id` or `class` names.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not saying you should do this, since I would get the periods out of the id names, but this will work with '.'s in the excursion code:

```
$('[id="tourName_' + excursion.code + '"]');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/e3cxo97q/